# MediaCodec decoding to buffer does not work while decoding to surface works

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

The video decoding code of an app is typical, just like the example code in the [MediaCodec document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#queueInputBuffer(int,%20int,%20int,%20long,%20int)). Nothing special. The configuration statement is like the following:

```
myMediaCodec.configure(myMediaFormat, mySurface, null, 0);
```

Everything works fine.  However, if I change the above code to the following to decode the video to a buffer instead of a surface:

```
myMediaCodec.configure(myMediaFormat, null, null, 0);
```

then the following code:

```
int iOutputBufferIndex = myMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(myBufferInfo, 100000);
```

will always return MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER. Even more strangly, any subsequent call of myMediaCodec.stop() or myMediaCodec.release() will hang (i.e. the call never returns or generates an exception).
This happens on a generic (AGPTek) tablet (Allwinner A31S, 1.5GHz Cortex A7 Quad Core).  On a simulator and another tablet (Asus Memo Pad), everything works fine.

I am asking for any tip to help get around this problem.

Comment: FWIW, you can find some additional examples and information on bigflake (e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest).  What version of Android is running on the problematic device?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was waiting for your ultimate response. bigflake was the first place that I checked, but unfortunately the tablet runs on Android 4.2.2, so I cannot run the test.

Comment: There are known problems with pre-4.3 devices.  It wouldn't surprise me if this was a codec bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.  This helps me to stop wasting more time on this approach.  I will start plan B - your favorite SurfaceTexture approach.

Comment: @fadden Plan B still does not work with the AGPTek tablet, but works perfectly with an Asus tablet and an emulator.

Comment: The basic problem is that the only MediaCodec "tests" in Android 4.2 were apps like Youtube and Netflix.  If they didn't do it, the code paths weren't exercised, and nobody noticed if they were broken.  However, if decoding to a SurfaceView works, then I'd expect decoding to a SurfaceTexture to have a high probability of working.  Is it failing the same way as when decoding to a buffer?

Comment: Yes, it fails exactly the same way - constant INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER from dequeueOutputBuffer. Again, the exactly same code works perfectly with a Genymotion emulator and an Asus tablet.  BTW, the AGPTek tablet came with Android 4.1 originally, I upgraded the OS to 4.2.2 using AGPTek's official upgrading package(http://www.agptek.com/support/download.html).

Comment: @fadden I am sorry but I misstated the error  pattern. For plan B, the AGPTek tablet does generate the correct sequence of response:INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER, INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED, INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED.  However, the BufferInfo.size is always zero, so the image is never rendered using your code that uses BufferInfo.size to determine whether to render the image.

Comment: That sounds vaguely familiar... maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643307/decoding-h264-stream-bufferinfo-size-is-always-zero ?  Note that question is also working with 4.1/4.2 devices.

Comment: Extremely familiar. I don't know how my search missed it. Actually, everything looks fine if I take out the check of BufferInfo.size (i.e. force rendering every time). I forgot to mention this is how I have been doing with displaying the video on a surface.   It does not seem to hurt anything.  approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you provide one single input buffer worth of data before trying this, or do you pass as many packets as you can before `dequeueInputBuffer` also blocks or returns `INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER`? A decoder might not output data after only one packet of input (if the decoder has got some delay), but if it works with Suface output it should probably behave in the same way there.

If that (queueing as many input buffers as possible) doesn't work, I would say that this sounds like a decoder bug.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just like using surface, hundreds of data packets have been fed to the decoder to test this.  I was also thinking this might be a decoder bug, and wondering if there would be way to get around this, at least to prevent it from hanging.